# Using Sed to Match A Pattern and Prepend line

Tags: unix, sed

I'm trying to use sed to search and match a pattern (regular expression) and prepend the match line with double dash (--). Basically, I have the following in my file :

```
alter user SYS identified by values '' ;
alter user PUBLIC identified by values '' ;
alter user DBA identified by values '' ;
alter user SYSTEM identified by values 
'S:F7A01360E1EECD3565AF171EF5A4109AC6656ABB9F0A1FA6EC11207AB091' ;
'S:82D55FF7743E74B4FCCF4DD2538C161DA2B29DE8688DBC8113EE4BAC9D49' ;
alter user EXP_FULL_DATABASE identified by values '' ;
```

I want it to look like this :

```
--alter user SYS identified by values '' ;
--alter user PUBLIC identified by values '' ;
--alter user DBA identified by values '' ;
alter user SYSTEM identified by values 
'S:F7A01360E1EECD3565AF171EF5A4109AC6656ABB9F0A1FA6EC11207AB091' ;
 'S:82D55FF7743E74B4FCCF4DD2538C161DA2B29DE8688DBC8113EE4BAC9D49' ;
--alter user EXP_FULL_DATABASE identified by values '' ;
```

I tried the following but no luck:

sed /\values '' ; /s/^/--/ alterpwd.sql >> alterpwd_new.sql

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/values '\'\'' ;$/s/^/--/' file
```

To pass a `'` through to sed, the underlying shell needs to be exposed and the `'` quoted i.e. `sed '/'\'\''/d' file` would delete lines containing to two adjacent single quotes.

Comment: It worked for me if i use gnu version of sed (i'm on os x)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sed 's/^alter.*values \x27\x27 ;$/--&/' file
```

or

```
sed "s/^alter.*values '' ;$/--&/" file
```

Note the outer quote in both commands. Using double quote allows to embed single quote.

With single quoted `sed` script, you need to use the single quote ascii character `/x27`.

Comment: Thanks Oliv, but none of the suggested solution worked.